# Rails Ajax redrawing html doesn't recognize relations between models

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I am redrawing my html with javascript after I get a response through my ajax, which is working fine. The only thing that is not displayed when redrawing is the Book[i].user.full_name
and the helper method cutoff_text("books[i].author")

It says that it is undefined for both. Does that mean I cannot redraw that specific html and helper methods if my Model has a relation to another model? How can I fix this?

Because books belong_to user

This is my code:

```
$('#priceSelect').change(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "books",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      sort: $('#priceSelect :selected').val(),
      title: $('.title_information').data('title'),
      university: $('.university_information').data('university')
    },
    success: function(result){
      // result gives me an array of my book objects
      var books = result;
      var length = books.length;
      var html = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        .
        .
        .
        html += "<h5 class='no-margin'>" + "<%= cutoff_text(" + books[i].author + ") %></h5>";
        html += "<h5 class='no-margin book-price-highlight'>" + books[i].price + "€</h5>";
        html += "<h5 class='no-margin'>By " + books[i].user.full_name + "</h5>";
      }
      document.getElementById("book-id").innerHTML = html
    },
  })
});
```

BooksController.rb Index

```
@title = params.dig("book", "title")
@university = params.dig("users", "university")

if (params.dig("book", "title") != "" ) && (params.dig("users", "university") != "" )
  @books = Book.where({title: params.dig("book", "title")})
  .joins(:user).where(users: {university: params.dig("users", "university")})
elsif (params.dig("book", "title") != "" ) && (params.dig("users", "university") == "" )
  @books = Book.where({title: params.dig("book", "title")})
elsif (params.dig("book", "title") == "" ) && (params.dig("users", "university") != "" )
  @books = Book.joins(:user).where(users: {university: params.dig("users", "university")})
else
  @books = Book.all
end

case params[:sort]
  when "Price Descending"
    if (params[:title] != "" ) && (params[:university] != "" )
      @books = Book.where({title: params[:title]})
      .joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:university]}).order(price_cents: "DESC")
    elsif (params[:title] != "" ) && (params[:university] == "" )
      @books = Book.where({title: params[:title]}).order(price_cents: "DESC")
    elsif (params[:title] == "" ) && (params[:university] != "" )
      @books = Book.joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:university]}).order(price_cents: "DESC")
    else
      @books = Book.all.order(price_cents: "DESC")
    end
  when "Price Ascending"
    if (params[:title] != "" ) && (params[:university] != "" )
      @books = Book.where({title: params[:title]})
      .joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:university]}).order(price_cents: "ASC")
    elsif (params[:title] != "" ) && (params[:university] == "" )
      @books = Book.where({title: params[:title]}).order(price_cents: "ASC")
    elsif (params[:title] == "" ) && (params[:university] != "" )
      @books = Book.joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:university]}).order(price_cents: "ASC")
    else
      @books = Book.all.order(price_cents: "ASC")
    end
  when "Best Results"
    if (params[:title] != "" ) && (params[:university] != "" )
      @books = Book.where({title: params[:title]})
      .joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:university]}).sort_by(&:created_at)
    elsif (params[:title] != "" ) && (params[:university] == "" )
      @books = Book.where({title: params[:title]}).sort_by(&:created_at)
    elsif (params[:title] == "" ) && (params[:university] != "" )
      @books = Book.joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:university]}).sort_by(&:created_at)
    else
      @books = Book.all.sort_by(&:created_at)
    end
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @books }
end
```

And my index.html.erb view

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "title_information", data: {title: @title} do %>
<% end %>
<%= content_tag :div, class: "university_information", data: {university: @university} do %>
<% end %>

<select id="priceSelect">
  <option value="Best Results" selected="selected">Best Results</option>
  <option value="Price Descending">Price Descending</option>
  <option value="Price Ascending">Price Ascending</option>
</select>
.
.
.
<div class="books-info" id="book-id">
  <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <div class="col-xs-12 selectable-card">
      <%= link_to book_path(book.id) do %>
        <h4 class="index-card-title no-margin"><%= book.title %></h4>
        <h5 class="no-margin"><%= cutoff_text(book.author) %></h5>
        <h5 class="no-margin">By <%= book.user.full_name %></h5>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In my User.rb model:

```
def full_name
  "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
end
```

and lastly the helper method:

```
module BooksHelper
  def cutoff_text(string)
    string.length > 121 ? string.first(120) + "..." : string
  end
end
```

Comment: can you show whats coming in ajax response ???

Comment: paste controller and helper methods as well

Comment: The ajax response is: [{…}, {…}, {…}] with each of the {...} as book objects --> {id: 22, title: "Math", author: "Molissa", field: "Chemistry", price_cents: 2600, publish_year: "2007-04-28", title:"Math", user_id:15}

Comment: It works fine if I only rewrite html with the attributes from my book model, but as soon as i try doing something like book.user in the javascript it says that it's undefined

Comment: Issue is you are calling full_name helper method from client side javascript, which won't work. Either you should send user's full_name in json response or else you should render  html page back to client.

Comment: check my solution.You will understand whats the problem and the  solution will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why?**

Because full_name is server side logic and you are trying to call it 
  from client side javascript after receiving data, which won't work.
  You know what I mean?  Can you call controller action lets say 
  index directly from javascript? No right?. You have to use ajax or html
  and server will respond with data and then you can use it.

**What's Solution?**

return full_name in json itself. Like this

```
[{full_name: "first last", id: 22, title: "Math", author: "Molissa", field: "Chemistry", price_cents: 2600, publish_year: "2007-04-28", title:"Math", user_id:15}, {…}, {…}]
```

**How to do?**

> BooksController.rb

```
def index
  ...
  ...
  @books = @books.includes(:user)    // eager loading user. So that to reduce queries

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json                      // dont return @books directly.will handle it in jbuilder
  end

end
```

> create index.json.jbuilder (in same folder where your index.html file
>   present). Paste below code in it.

```
json.array! @books, partial: 'books/book', as: :book
```

> create _book.json.jbuilder (in same folder where your index.html file
>   present).Put the below code in it.

```
json.id book.id
json.title book.title
json.author book.author 
json.field book.field
json.price_cents book.price_cents
json.publish_year book.publish_year

json.user_id book.user_id
json.user_fullname  book.user.full_name            // here we are sending user's fullname.
```

**And Finally change your javascript little bit**

Now use can fetch user's fullname like books[i].user_fullname

```
$('#priceSelect').change(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "books",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      sort: $('#priceSelect :selected').val(),
      title: $('.title_information').data('title'),
      university: $('.university_information').data('university')
    },
    success: function(result){
      // result gives me an array of my book objects
      var books = result;
      var length = books.length;
      var html = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        .
        .
        .
        html += "<h5 class='no-margin'>" + "<%= cutoff_text(" + books[i].author + ") %></h5>";
        html += "<h5 class='no-margin book-price-highlight'>" + books[i].price + "€</h5>";
        html += "<h5 class='no-margin'>By " + books[i].user_fullname + "</h5>";    // check this
      }
      document.getElementById("book-id").innerHTML = html
    },
  })
});
```

Comment: it gives me a 500 error saying that undefined local variable or method `title' for #<#<Class:0x007f824cd13ca8>:0x007f8244de7290>
Did you mean?  @title:
  app/views/books/_book.json.jbuilder:2:in `_app_views_books__book_json_jbuilder___1060707560840941417_70098739575200' and this error xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

Comment: @WQ.Kevin  I forget to call attributes using book object. I update _book.json.jbuilder file.Check

Comment: Ok, I still have to learn a lot. I just followed your instructions and made some small changes serverside but it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean I cannot redraw that specific html and helper methods if my Model has a relation to another model?

No, it does not mean that. However...

The front end has no knowledge of your back end relationships. Which means that you have to pass all the required data in your json. So, you'll need to modify your `index` method (which is already not pretty) to do that.